# C struct value different in and outside function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

firstly there are few lines of my code:

```
typedef struct {
    char letter;
    ...
} Monster;

...

Monster *monsters;
load_monsters( monsters );

...

void load_monsters( Monster *monsters ) {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen( MONSTERSFILE, "rb" );
    int count;
    fread( &count, sizeof( count ), 1, file );
    monsters = malloc( count * sizeof( Monster ) );
    fread( monsters, sizeof( Monster ), count, file );
    fclose( file );
}
```

I have problem because values in monsters array i.e. monsters[0].letter are different in function and outside function. In function they're good but outside bad. I've checked address of pointer and inside and outside function it's the same. I don't understand why it's happening.

Comment: C11 draft standard `6.5.2.2 Function calls, Section 4 [...] In preparing for the call to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument. 93) A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the arguments. On the other hand, it is possible to pass a pointer to an object, and the function may change the value of the object pointed to. [...]`. TL;DR: C is call-by-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing Monster* by value (i.e. monsters[i] can be modified with the effect visible outside, but monsters - the pointer- itself is passed by value).

You are modifying monsters within the function (by assigning it the result of malloc). This change will not be visible outside the function.

Either allocate monsters outside the function, or pass Monster** to the function, allocate *monsters, and write to (*monsters)[i]

Comment: Or do the sane thing, and `return` the allocated `Monster *` instead of `void`.